Understanding などその他諸々
From Konosuba chapter 4, Megumin explains that she specializes in explosion magic only:

爆発系魔法威力上昇、高速詠唱などその他諸々、爆裂魔法にすべてを捧げたスキル構成です

How do I make sense of this sentence grammatically? I am a bit confused with などその他諸々 part. I can't tell whether「爆発系魔法威力上昇、高速詠唱などその他諸々」is the subject for this sentence, or they are just examples of skills that are in スキル構成. Does ～などその他諸々 mean "many things other than ～" or "～, and many others beside ～"? Is その他諸々 another way to say など?
Also, does スキル構成 mean the same thing as スキルセット or スキル組み合わせ?



その他諸々 is an emphatic way of saying など. It's like などなど, "and many others", "many things including ～", "and such and such", "etc etc", or "and so on and on". This is typically used without など.
"爆発系魔法威力上昇、高速詠唱など(その他諸々)" is not the subject of the sentence. It's a list serving as a description of the スキル構成.
スキル構成 is almost the same as スキルセット, but スキル組み合わせ is not a common phrase. You usually need to say スキルの組み合わせ instead.


爆発系魔法威力上昇、高速詠唱などその他諸々、爆裂魔法にすべてを捧げたスキル構成です
(This/Mine) is a skill configuration entirely dedicated to explosion magic, with Explosion Magic Power Boost, Rapid Casting, and many others.

